# after setup GData ios client in xcode4, can't use OAuth

Tags: objective-c, ios, gdata

I follow [this blog](http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/) to setup GData to my ios project, build success, everything is ok, but when I add a GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch view to my window, it just **show a black view without anything**. The code built GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch in my project was copy from http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/. In gtm-oauth2 project, the OAuth is work, I don't know why the same code can't work in my new project.

my code:

GDAppDelegate.h:

```
@interface GDAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
@private
    UIWindow *_window;
    UINavigationController *mNavigationController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) GDViewController *viewController;

@end
```

GDAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "GDAppDelegate.h"
#import "GData.h"
#import "GTMOAuth2SignIn.h"
#import "GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.h"
@implementation GDAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    UINavigationController *mainNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nil];
    mainNavigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-20);
    [mainNavigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
    [mainNavigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];

    NSString *keychainItemName = nil;
    NSString *scope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";

    NSString *clientID = @"181779079861.apps.googleusercontent.com";//self.clientIDField.text;
    NSString *clientSecret = @"FAIi_4YiI3vAtYi7Xf1nMF7Q";//self.clientSecretField.text;


    SEL finishedSel = @selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:);

    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;
    viewController = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch controllerWithScope:scope
                                                              clientID:clientID
                                                          clientSecret:clientSecret
                                                      keychainItemName:keychainItemName
                                                              delegate:self
                                                      finishedSelector:finishedSel];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"en"
                                                       forKey:@"hl"];
    viewController.signIn.additionalAuthorizationParameters = params;

    NSString *html = @"<html><body bgcolor=silver><div align=center>Loading sign-in page...</div></body></html>";
    viewController.initialHTMLString = html;


    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Just so you're aware. In your code example your clientSecret is visible to all of us. You may want to reset the secret if you are using this code in production (I hope not)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by add GData and OAuth lib classes directly to my app

Comment: I'm having the same problem, can you go into more detail please? Thanks.

Comment: Hi bang can u please help me in using Gdata to get email id of friends from gmail account. Ihave Gone through the google gdata documentation it is very confusing and complex. can u please suggest a good tutorial or some help to solve my problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and had to include the GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch.xib file into my main solution. Otherwise, using the static library worked fine.

It seems that the .xib files have to be copied into the app's resources folder so that it can load them.